# Duplicating dropdown filter items from API - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api

I have created my drop down menu , but unfortunately it recieves an duplicated value from the API . I receive certain amount of documents from the BE and some of the are have the same name so in my dropdown i receive a duplication of the names . My code looks like this :

My function

```
divideItems = () => {

        let startIndex = ((parseInt(this.state.activePaginationTab) + 1) * this.state.rowsPerPage) - this.state.rowsPerPage;
        let endIndex = (parseInt(this.state.activePaginationTab) + 1) * this.state.rowsPerPage - 1;
        let tabItems = [];

        for (let i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
            if (this.state.items[i]) {
                tabItems.push(this.state.items[i]);
            }
        }

        this.setState({
            tabItems: tabItems
        }, () => {

        });
```

My Rendering

```
<RBS.Dropdown>
     <RBS.Dropdown.Toggle  id="dropdown-invoice-header">
          {translations.type}
     </RBS.Dropdown.Toggle>

         <RBS.Dropdown.Menu>
              {this.state.tabItems.map(item => (
       <RBS.Dropdown.Item >{item.documentType}</RBS.Dropdown.Item>
))}
           </RBS.Dropdown.Menu>
      </RBS.Dropdown>
```

The result duplicating items in my dropdown menu .

[image]

Comment: do you have duplicated entries in `state.tabItems` as well?

Comment: Yes , because it is an table i use `state.tabItems` also a little bit further .

Answer (score 0):

Remove the duplicates

```
const uniqueItems = [];
tabItems.map(item => {
    if (uniqueItems.indexOf(item.documentType) === -1) {
        uniqueItems.push(item.documentType)
    }
});


this.setState({
    tabItems: uniqueItems 
}, () => {
```

Comment: there is no value after the arrow function `item=>`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the duplicates before setting the state:

```
for (let i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
    if (this.state.items[i] && tabItems.indexOf(this.state.items[i]) === -1) {
        tabItems.push(this.state.items[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @PandaMastr can you try `console.log(tabItems);` after the for-loop to see if it actually is being filtered

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) from ES6, because *Set* doesn't allow duplicates and will remove from array if found:

`uniqueItems = [...new Set(tabItems)];`

or shorter:

`[new Set(tabItems)].map(item => { 
    // do stuff 
});`

or you can do .filter before and then .map:

`uniqueItems = tabItems.filter((item, index) {
    return a.indexOf(index) == index;
});`

Comment: Yes , but i recieve back an empty array